# Navigate until there is no sheet left

Tags: vba, excel

I have a task for school. On my worksheet there is a button with next sheet and previous sheet. But I want that it always checks if possible to move to the next sheet.

For example, three sheets. I start on sheet 1 and click next. Then on sheet 2 I click next. I'm on sheet 3 and I click next, so a message box comes up "there are no sheets left." but if I add another sheet it needs to move on to sheet 4.

Here is the code that I already have:

```
If ActiveSheet.Index = Worksheets.Count Then
Worksheets(1).Select

Else
ActiveSheet.Previous.Select
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If ActiveSheet.Index <> Worksheets.Count Then

    ActiveSheet.Next.Select

Else

    MsgBox "There are no more sheets left."

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

if you aim to simply add Command Button to every page then you would have to copy this code in each of the command buttons on all pages(design mode-doubleclick the command button)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim sheetnum As Integer

sheetnum = ActiveSheet.Index
If sheetnum = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate
    MsgBox "You are at last sheet returning to the first sheet."
Else
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetnum + 1).Activate

End If
End Sub
```

Or you would have to create a module and call function from command button.
Like this:
In CommandButton code on every page:

```
Call newpage
```

In Module1:

```
Public Sub newpage()
Dim sheetnum As Integer

sheetnum = ActiveSheet.Index
If sheetnum = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate
    MsgBox "You are at last sheet returning to the first sheet."
Else
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetnum + 1).Activate

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It's just simply Command Buttons. The code works but the messagebox don't appear and I stay in the same sheet then.

Comment: Look if you have any hidden sheets. 
the code just goes like
sheetnum=number of currently selected sheet
if sheetnum = count of sheets in workbook -> the count is the same as number of last sheet
then activate first sheet and start msgbox
if we are not on the last page just run forward